# How can I stop an object property access chain under certain conditions?

Tags: javascript

1. Object A has an array of instances of Object B.
2. Object A also has a getter method that takes in an index and returns the relevant Object B.
3. Object B has a set of methods that can be called.

I'm trying to call the object B method using an object chain ( a.getB().method() )like below:

```js
class ObjectB{
  foo(){return 'bar'}
}

class ObjectA{
  constructor(){
    this.list = []
   }
  addB(){this.list.push(new ObjectB)}
  getB(index) { if(index < this.list.length) return this.list[index]}
}

a = new ObjectA();
a.addB();
a.getB(0).foo(); // Works
a.getB(4).foo(); // Returns error, since getB(4) is undefined and has no foo()
```

I tried different else statements in getB() but I can't stop the script from trying to access 'output'.foo().

I tried a try catch in getB(), but I can't force it to give an error at getB(4). Is there a clean way from me to handle this potential issue without try/catching every instance of the last line?

Comment: You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).  `a.getB(4)?.foo()`

Comment: The reason you are getting error is because a.getB(4) doesn't return anything so its undefined and you are trying to access foo on undefined. The easiest way is optional chaining as mentioned by many here or you can make use of a conditional expression and more. Also, you could try doing a separate function which takes in both of these and returns based on availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the optional chaining operator:
`a.getB(4)?.foo()`
You can also add it for function calls:
`a.getB(4)?.foo?.()`. This last solution works if `getB(4)` returns an object that is defined, but has no `foo` function.

Comment: I recommend you to use the optional chaining operator. Another idea is you could return a dummy when there is no B at index.

Comment: This is great! I didn't know optional chaining was a thing. Everyday I like Javascript a bit more. I can't see a difference between the two solutions you put though, I assume the base example doesn't have the second optional chaining operator?

Comment: You're right. That was a typo. I've updated my answer. The first example works fine if `getB()` returns `undefined`, thus, avoiding access of a property from an `undefined` object. But this will still crash if `getB()` returns and object which is defined, let's say an empty object `{}`, but this returned object has no `foo` function. The last example works for both of these cases.